# Why the step "Get_from_session" does not work in ios with corvertigo server 7.7?

Tags: convertigo

We are storing values in the aplication session using only “set in session” and “get from session” steps.

We have several apps in a production environment with a Convertigo Server 7.4. whit convertigo project in ionic 3 and angular 5, a and we have migrated to convertigo server 7.7. convertigo project in ionic 5 and angular 8. We have configured the properties"Context timeout" and "HTTP session timeout" in 3600 secons.

When we test on an android device everything works correctly, but when we test on an ios device it has no value in expression of the step "Get from session"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LgHx.png)

The value between the step "Set_Token" in "Login" sequence and the step "Get_token" in "ServicesData" sequence is lost, however if the step "Get from session" is in the sequence "Login" after step "Set_token", it works and it only happens in ios.

Comparing logs between the ios app and the android app the difference I see is that in ios it shows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dikl9.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEm5O.png)
and on android it shows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ospgI.png)

Why with convertigo server 7.7 the step "Get_from_session" works on android and not on ios?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Steps in a sequence are executed on the server and are platform indepedendants.

Make sure that calls to **Login** and **ServicesData** sequences are made on the same JSESSIONID.
For instance, in the iOS logs, the **Login** sequence is called using the **56B4DA...D34D** JSESSIONID and the **ServicesData** with **85CD3D...0A19**, so this is normal that the Step "GetFromSession" in ServicesData does not retrieve value from Step "SetInSession" from Login sequence.

You must preserve the same session between sequences calls.

Hope that Helps.

Regards,

Gregory.

Comment: For more discussion privacy on your project, you can contact us at support[at]convertigo.com